# Is there a way to configure the UI of DocuSign when viewing a signed agreement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack, docusignapi

I am writing a tool for customer support that will allow the support personnel to view a document signed by the customer. However, using EnvelopesApi.CreateRecipientView() does not expose the ability to remove the "Other Actions" drop-down menu from the header. None of those options are relevant for the support personnel. Is it possible to customize the DocuSign document viewing page?

I've read through all of the documentation I could find online for the REST API and I've dug through the options presented in the Admin section of the DocuSign account, but I haven't come across anything that exposes that level of configuration.

Here's a snippet of how I'm generating the DocuSign url now:

```cs
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(configuration);

var viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
    {
        ReturnUrl = request.ReturnUrl,
        ClientUserId = request.UserId.ToString(),
        AuthenticationMethod = "email",
        UserName = $"{request.FirstName} {request.LastName}",
        Email = request.EmailAddress
    };

var recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(loginInfo.AccountId, request.DocuSignDocumentKey, viewOptions);

return new ViewSignedAgreementResponse()
    {
        RecipientViewDocumentViewUrl = recipientView.Url
    };
```

Again, I haven't seen any other account settings or API options that will allow anonymous viewing of a previously signed document while also configuring which buttons/actions are available.

Comment: is your requirement to show Document to the support person or to use DocuSign UI to show the document? The RecipientViewURL is the UI for creating signing URL for the recipient to sign the document. Also whats the reason to show the document to support person? are they some to review and approve something on the document?

Comment: To echo Amit's comment, it might be better to make an API call to get the combined document, then show that within your application.

Comment: @AmitKBist The requirement is to allow the support person to view and print. Because of constraints with the POS system, showing the DocuSign UI is the best option. We also cannot download the document as a file per the system constraints.

Comment: @Drew What do you mean by the combined document? Do you mean downloading the document as a file? Because of the constraints of the workstations, we cannot download a file to the computer, and other document-rendering techniques would require a lot of customization. That can be done but I was hoping DocuSign allowed options: it would be a prettier outcome :-)

Comment: If Support person needs to see each and every envelope to View and Print, then why don't you add them as Carbon Copy recipient in each and every envelope. That way they will be able to access the envelope anytime from the DocuSign email or from DocuSign Web Account.

Comment: @AmitKBist It's a little more complicated than that. there are >1500 locations, each with support people. Location 1 shouldn't access Location 2's documents. Also, we don't want to have all support personnel logging into DocuSign because of added time to each of their days and no emails because we're trying to cut down on # of "communications" to each location. But thank you for seeking alternative solutions!

Comment: do you want to show Document to Support people after envelope is completed or still in Pending state? and does your signer is an embedded Signer in your envelopes?

Comment: @AmitKBist The support people will only see the document after then envelope is completed. The signer will sign document anonymously via a link to DocuSign

Comment: If signer is signing via DocuSign email then there is no way to create RecipientView URL with API. But if Signer would have been an embedded Signer, then I would have asked you to use same RecipientViewURL for the support with signer's clientUserId after envelope is completed, and at this time they would not be seeing those Other Actions options.

Comment: The signer is signing via a DocuSign redirect embedded in an online process. Then the signer is redirected back into the process via the return url. We create the envelope and then use the same envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView() method to generate the signing url. Therefore, according to my example and the documentation, I can create a viewing experience by calling envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView() with the same information.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community Justin C!

Your question relates to DocuSign UI and not the way you are handling API calls. In order to modify the UI and remove the existing links or buttons, you need to consider working on the [Resource Files](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-signing-resource-file-v2-0).

You can download the master resource files in DocuSign Admin > Brands > Signing > Resource Files (at the very bottom of the page).

There are 2 different resource files for either "Signing" experience or "Email" notifications. These let you develop your own user interface, however, it might require more development than expected.